# Safety of using class destructor to output logging info

Tags: c++

I have a lot of code that processes engineering data and frequently need to output intermediate data I read into Matlab for further analysis. Often I just want to print the logged data after execution but sometimes to a file.

I put the `Log` class and one or more objects of `Log` in a common header file. For simplicity, I use the dtor to output the data and so its critical that the dtor is called while the program can still execute I/O. I presume `inline` operates to ensure there is only a single instance of each of the `Log` objects.  I'm not using this in multiple threads. Is this safe?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <format>

class Log {
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    std::string filename;
public:
    Log(const std::string& filename = "") : filename(filename) {}
    void add(const std::string& arg) {v.emplace_back(arg); }
    ~Log() {
        if (filename.length()==0)
            for (const auto& x:v)
                std::cout << x << '\n';
        else
        {
            std::ofstream out(filename);
            for (const auto& x : v)
                out << x << '\n';
        }
    }
};

inline Log logger1;             // console out at end of execution
inline Log logger2("out.txt");  // output to a file
// Above is in a header common to all code


int main()
{
    logger1.add(std::format("logger1 {}", 1));
    logger2.add(std::format("logger2 {}", 2));
    logger1.add(std::format("logger1 {}", 3));
    logger2.add(std::format("logger2 {}", 4));
}
// Output Console:
// 1
// 3
// Output out.txt
// 2
// 4
```

Comment: Yes it is safe. A destructor is just a function. You can do whatever you want in it.

Comment: If you add code to the destructor that may throw an exception, then the code is not safe unless you wrap it in a `try/catch` block.

Comment: Is that really what `inline` does?

Comment: Also,  maybe check in the destructor if the file is open before writing to it.

Comment: [Inline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline) could protect you from [ODR](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) violation, e.g. if you would define your loggers in a header. In your case, where you define them in cpp (and the one with `main` function) it has no effect.

Comment: @pptaszni Yes, as noted in the code it's to be included in a common header file which also includes the `inline` statements. Just simplifies my back and forth from lab measurements to c++ program and sometimes to Matlab. Kind of a discovery process then incorporating the statistical info. The logger code should not be used for logging in the usual sense. Just not sure what else to call it. Purely a temporary add during the lab work.

Answer (score 1):

This is not safe. If your program crashes the destructor will not be called and you will not get a log output, making the logger borderline useless. The logger is not thread safe either. You will need to add some synchronization primitives like `mutex` in the `add()` function.

Instead of creating your own logger. Use `spdlog` it is widely used and heavily tested and optimized.

Comment: I know the dtor won't be called if the program crashes. But this is not a problem or something in production code. It's just to make it easy for me to collect data for further analysis of the data and possible modification of the code based on that. Logger isn't used in threads though the file option should work providing the Log objects aren't global and log calls are all within a single thread.

Comment: Then why are you asking if it is safe? I can see atleast 7 more issues/improvements with this code e.g. Rule of 5 violation. But there is no point listing them out. You would just say "This is not a problem or something in production code".

Comment: This is really an unusual use case. While I suppose I could add `=deleted` to unused special members I don't have any reason to use them in the first place. It's purely an interim convenience for lab work interacting between measurement collection, c++ run, and potentially Matlab further analysis. My concern was not knowing where the dtor would be located. If it just selects one of the multiple cpp files with the included header then no problem. It's made my life simpler doing the lab work.